# How to print a list of extensions compiled with php

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm trying to find out what extensions are compiled with the php binary I've been given. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

For example, it's possible to check what version of an extension/library is there

```
var_dump(curl_version());
```

but this means I have to check one by one, and I may not be able to guess all libraries compiled within. So anyway to get php to tell me what extensions it has compiled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the [`get_loaded_extensions()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) function?

You can use it in combination with [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/phpversion) which will give you the version for PHP and (if provided as parameter) the extension:

```
$a = array_map(function($e) { return sprintf("%s (%s)", $e, phpversion($e)); }, get_loaded_extensions());
echo implode('<br>', $a);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Bucxm5)

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I see this syntax for adding functions. What's the `($e)` being passed as a parameter?

Comment: But I'm wondering, are loaded extensions the same as compiled extensions? For example in wampserver, I see a list of many extensions, but some of them aren't activated (don't have a tick mark next to them), so those aren't loaded, but they're compiled, and I can load them if I want to. I think there's a difference between loaded and compiled/available.

Comment: @sameold - This clever addition actually came from hakre, but I can explain it. The first line in a call to `array_map`, which takes a callback function as its first parameter. The line `function($e)` is creating an unnamed function in-line, which will then be applied to each element in the array. When it is called, the value `$e` is populated with the current array element. As for your other comment, I am not sure, your best bet is to try it. I would guess you are correct and that it will only work for loaded extensions, not compiled ones.

Comment: One possibility if you want to know which extensions can be dynamically loaded is to grab the `extensions_dir` php.ini directive using `ini_get('extension_dir');` and check out what files present.

Answer (score 3):

`php -m` in the console will show you a list of modules. Not sure if that counts as 'programmatic'.